# MongoDB - Project data based on array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having student data with two parents:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('643f8a6773a92fb1552e4c89'),
  studentName: 'Peter Jackson',
  studentId: 'SID1001',
  grade: 2,
  gender: 'Male',
  parentDetails: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId('63fee5a42f60946679146768'),
        name: 'Jackson Steve',
        email: 'jack.steve@gmail.com',
        mobile: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        relation: 'Father'
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('6447c1ba22670472ed4b29cc'),
        name: 'Amenda Jackson',
        email: 'amenda.jack@gmail.com',
        mobile: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        relation: 'Mother'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to show the student data based on each parent like below:

```
[
  {
    studentId: 'SID1001',
    studentName: 'Peter Jackson',
    grade: 2,
    parentName: 'Jackson Steve',
    parentEmail: 'jack.steve@gmail.com',
    relation: 'Father'
  },
  {
    studentId: 'SID1001',
    studentName: 'Peter Jackson',
    grade: 2,
    parentName: 'Amenda Jackson',
    parentEmail: 'amenda.jack@gmail.com',
    relation: 'Mother'
  }
]
```

Need to show individual parent details with their child details.
Need some valuable help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `parentDetails` array into multiple documents.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output document to desired output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$parentDetails"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      studentName: 1,
      studentId: 1,
      grade: 1,
      parentName: "$parentDetails.name",
      parentEmail: "$parentDetails.email",
      relation: "$parentDetails.relation"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XAuUqD_RPy7)